Js Data not dispalying on Frontend
I am trying to show this data from an array in a .js file in the frontend but it doesnt show. Its just blank and i dont know what is wrong. i have done the imports right and everything.
The js file:
  import lemonBottle from "./assets/lemon-bottle.webp";
  import garlicBottle from "./assets/garlic-bottle.webp";
  import rosemaryBottle from "./assets/rosemary-bottle.webp";
  import chiliBottle from "./assets/chili-bottle.webp";
  import delicateBottle from "./assets/delicate-bottle.webp";
  import mediumBottle from "./assets/medium-bottle.webp";
  import boldBottle from "./assets/bold-bottle.webp";

  export const products = [
  {
  id: "234",
  name: "Lemon",
  price: "$26.00",
  imageName: lemonBottle,
  },
  {
  id: "345",
  name: "Garlic",
  price: "$26.00",
  imageName: garlicBottle,
  },
  {
  id: "456",
  name: "Rosemary",
  price: "$26.00",
  imageName: rosemaryBottle,
  },
  {
  id: "567",
  name: "Chili",
  price: "$26.00",
  imageName: chiliBottle,
  },
  {
  id: "678",
  name: "Delicate",
  price: "$24.50",
  imageName: delicateBottle,
  },
  {
  id: "789",
  name: "Medium",
  price: "$24.50",
  imageName: mediumBottle,
  },
  {
  id: "890",
  name: "Bold",
  price: "$24.50",
  imageName: boldBottle,
  },
  ];

Here is the code for the front-end:
    <template>
    <div class="shop mt-20 border mx-auto w-4/6">
    <div class="product-grid md:grid grid-cols-3 md:gap-10 mt-10 p-5">
    <div
    class="border shop-item mb-5"
    v-for="product in products"
    :key="product.id"
  >
    <img class="h-[450px] w-[350px]" :src="product.imageName" />

    <p class="mt-1 text-wrap text-left text-2xl text-gray-500 font-bold">
      {{ product.name }}
    </p>
    <p class="mt-1 text-wrap text-left text-3xl font-bold">
      {{ product.price }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { products } from "@/product-data";
console.log("Products:", products);
export default {
name: "ShopView",
data() {
return {
  products: [],
};
},
};
</script>

It displays blank and after inspection on the page the code between the <div shop-grid doesn't show up.

In the script section, you should do this instead:
<script>
import { products } from "../data";
export default {
  name: "ShopView",
  data() {
    return {
      products: products, //instead of an empty array
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Products:", products);
  },
};
</script>

importing the products array isn't enough. You need to initialize it in the data section.

Thanks! i guess the empty array was the problem. but why?? it worked for me on some other one before.

Haha, maybe you did something different you didn't take note of. These things happen, don't beat yourself up about it :)

Thank you anyway! you've been of great help. i was raging yesterday lol.
